# How to fix ”unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path” error in circleci

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, circleci

I'm setting up circle-ci to automatically build/deploy to AWS ECR &ECS.
But build is failed due to no `Dockerfile`.
Maybe this is because I set `docker-compose` for multiple docker images.
But I don't know how to resolve this issue.
Is there no way to make `DockerFile` instead of `docker-compose`?

- front: React
- backend: Golang
- ci-tool: circle-ci
- db: mysql

```
article
　├ .circleci
　├ client
　├ api  
　└ docker-compose.yml
```

I set .circleci/config.yml.

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@6.0.0
  aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@0.0.8

workflows:
  build_and_push_image:
    jobs:
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          region: AWS_REGION
          account-url: AWS_ECR_ACCOUNT_URL
          repo: 'article-ecr-jpskgc'
          tag: '${CIRCLE_SHA1}'
      - aws-ecs/deploy-service-update:
          requires:
            - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image
          family: 'article-task-jpskgc'
          cluster-name: 'article-cluster-jpskgc'
          service-name: 'article-service-jpskgc'
          container-image-name-updates: 'container=article-container-jpskgc,tag=${CIRCLE_SHA1}'
```

Here is the source code in github.
https://github.com/jpskgc/article

I expect build/deploy via circle-ci to ECR/ECS to success, but it actually fails.
This is the error log on circle-ci.

```
Build docker image
Exit code: 1
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
docker build \
   \
  -f Dockerfile \
  -t $AWS_ECR_ACCOUNT_URL/article-ecr-jpskgc:${CIRCLE_SHA1} \
  .
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/circleci/project/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
Exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a `Dockerfile`, check out the documentation for the orb you are using. Please read through them [here](https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/circleci/aws-ecr#jobs-build-and-push-image). Also `docker-compose` ≠ `docker`, therefore I will confirm that one cannot be used in substitution for the other.

Given your `docker-compose.yml`, I have a few suggestions for your general setup and CI.

For reference here is the `docker-compose.yml` in question:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: article
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: docker
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    ports:
      - 2345:2345
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

From the above we have the various components, just as you have stated:

- MySQL Database
- Nginx Loadbalancer
- Client App
- API Server

Here are my recommendations for each component:

**MySQL Database**

- Since you are deploying to AWS I recommend deploying a MySQL instance on the free tier, please follow this documentation: [https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/). With this you can remove your database from CI, which is recommended as ECS is not the ideal service to run a MySQL server.

**Nginx Loadbalancer**

- Because you are using ECS, this is not required as AWS handles all load balancing for you and is redundant.

**Client App**

- Because this is a react application, you shouldn't deploy to ECS -- this is not cost effective you would rather deploy this to Amazon S3. There are many resources on how to do this. You may follow [this guide](https://blog.cloudboost.io/react-with-circleci-aws-s3-and-aws-cloudfront-844a1b2c75c9) though you may have to make a few change based of the structure of your repository.
- This will reduce your overall cost and it makes more sense than an entire Docker container running just to serve static files.

**API Server**

- This is the only thing that should be running in ECS, and all you need to do is point to the correct `Dockerfile` in your configuration for it be built and pushed successfully.
- You may therefore edit your `circle ci` config as follows, assuming we are using the same `Dockerfile` in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
build_and_push_image:
    jobs:
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          region: AWS_REGION
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
          path: ./api
          account-url: AWS_ECR_ACCOUNT_URL
          repo: 'article-ecr-jpskgc'
          tag: '${CIRCLE_SHA1}'
```

**Things to Note**

My answer does not include:

- How to load balance your API service please follow these docs on how to do so: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html
- Details on setting up the MySQL server, it assumed you will follow the AWS documentation provided above.

Things you must do:

- Point your client app to the API server, this will probably require a code change from what I've seen.
- I want to stress that you must Load balance your API server according to [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html) yet again.
- You do not need to edit your `docker-compose.yml`